# Android Studio sort the value from TextView in a ListView

Tags: sorting, android-studio, listview, textview

I try to sort my ListView with the date from TextView.

In the Screenshots you can see my ToDo List, one TextView stores the Due Date. I try to sort the ListView with the dates, but i do not know how to do it right.

[image]
[image]

Here is the Code i could find in a Tutorial, but it does not work for me.

```
public class ToDoOverview extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView lv;
    List<ToDo> dataSource;
    ToDoOverviewListAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_to_do_overview);

        this.lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listToDo);
        this.dataSource = ToDoDatabaseHelper.getInstance(this).readAllToDos();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.menu_NewToDo:
                createToDo();
                return true;
            case R.id.menu_dailyToDo:
                showDailyToDo();
                return true;
            case R.id.menu_Sort_Fav:
                sortFav();
                return true;
            case R.id.menu_Sort_Date:
                sortDate();
                return true;
            case R.id.menu_Sort_Progress:
                sortProg();
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

public void sortDate(){
    adapter.sort(new Comparator<ToDo>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(ToDo todo1, ToDo todo2) {
            if(todo1.getDueDate() != null && todo2.getDueDate() != null){
                long date = todo1.getDueDate().compareTo(todo2.getDueDate());
            if(date != 0) {
                refreshListView();
                return (int) date;
            } else if(todo1.getDueDate() != null){
                refreshListView();
                return -1;
            } else if(todo2.getDueDate() != null){
                refreshListView();
                return 1;
            }
            return todo1.getName().compareToIgnoreCase(todo2.getName());
        }
    });
}
```

And here is My ToDoOverviewListAdapter Class:

```
public class ToDoOverviewListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ToDo> {

   public ToDoOverviewListAdapter(Context context, List<ToDo> objects) {
        super(context, 0, objects);
   }

   @Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       ToDo currentToDo = (ToDo) getItem(position);
       View view = convertView;
       if(view == null){
           view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.todo_overview_listitem, parent, false);
       }

       // First Step
       ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvName)).setText(currentToDo.getName());
       TextView dueDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvDueDate);
       ImageView fav = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.favIcon);
       TextView progStatus = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.progStatus);

       if(currentToDo.getDueDate() == null){
           dueDate.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
       } else {
           dueDate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
           dueDate.setText(currentToDo.getDueDate());
       }
       if(currentToDo.isFavorite()){
           fav.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
       }else{
           fav.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
       }
       if(currentToDo.getProgress() == null){
           progStatus.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
       } else {
           progStatus.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
           progStatus.setText(currentToDo.getProgress());
       }
       return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: Since `ToDoDatabaseHelper.getInstance(this).readAllToDos()` read all the dates from a db, Why don't you set an `order by` clause in the statement that fetches the rows?

Comment: thanks .. i did not make it with order by. if i click now on sort i do not go over .readAllToDos() anymore and now  it works fine. thanks